# How To Run MPI Python Script across multiple nodes on Slurm cluster? Error: Warning: can't run 1 processes on 2 nodes, setting nnodes to 1

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm running a script on a Slurm cluster that could benefit from parallel processing, so I'm trying to implement MPI. However, it doesn't seem to allow me to run processes on multiple nodes. I don't know if this is normally done automatically, but whenever I set --nodes=2 in the batch file for submission, I get the error message, "Warning: can't run 1 processes on 2 nodes, setting nnodes to 1."

I've been trying to get it to work with a simple Hello World script, but still run into the above error. I added --oversubscribe to the options when I run the MPI script, but still get this error.

````sh
    #SBATCH --job-name=a_test
    #SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
    #SBATCH --ntasks=1
    #SBATCH --cpu-freq=high
    #SBATCH --nodes=2
    #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
    #SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1gb
    #SBATCH --mem-bind=verbose,local
    #SBATCH --time=01:00:00
    #SBATCH --output=out_%x.log

    module load python/3.6.2
    mpirun -np 4 --oversubscribe python par_PyScript2.py
```bash

I still get the expected output, but only after the error message "Warning: can't run 1 processes on 2 nodes, setting nnodes to 1." I'm worried that without being able to run on multiple nodes, my actual script will be a lot slower.
````

Comment: Is your python script actually MPI parallelized? Sorry for asking but just double checking. People have misconceptions about MPI. Also, on my slurm I use `srun` and not `mpirun`. And finally, asking for 2 nodes for 4 processes is extremely inefficient - inter-node communication is much slower then intra-node. If you can run your job on one node, don't spread it across nodes. Avoid it except if your nodes only have only 2 processes each or you're for instance running out of one node's RAM and need more to handle the job.

Comment: Gladly. Can you post your script and maybe a link to that tutorial? I never ran python with mpi. My command for C and C++ with slurm is `srun -n #processes executable` + some other system dependent options. I choose the number of nodes in a similar way by typing `#SBATCH -N #nodes`. I run the whole thing either through `salloc` interactive session or  with `sbatch runscript`. Based on the message though your code is only ran in serial i.e. on one process/rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the warning is this line:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
```

where you're specifying that you're going to run only 1 mpi process, just before you request 2 nodes.

[`--ntasks`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#lbAB) sets the number of processes to run/ranks to use in your case. You then overwrite it with an equivalent `-n` which is why you're seeing the result.

For your reference, this is the script I run on my system,

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -C knl 
#SBATCH -q regular
#SBATCH -t 00:10:00

#SBATCH --nodes=2

module load python3

START_TIME=$SECONDS

srun -n 4 python mpi_py.py >& py_${SLURM_JOB_ID}.log

ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))
echo $ELAPSED_TIME
```

Performance notes:

- It's faster to run your code on the same node if possible. Internode communication is slower than within a node, it may be a bit slower but may also be much much slower which depends on things like cluster architecture.
- Consult your cluster settings recommendations. For instance on mine I should be adding certain slurm options to this script - specifically `-c` and `cpu_bind=` (more [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/mc_support.html#flags)).

Comment: You're welcome, it was good to get familiar with MPI in Python :)